# Declaring controller in html same as parent state

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router and have nested states with views.  I currently have my controller running twice, because it is declared in the app.js file and in `ng-controller`.  I need to set the `ng-controller` in the html file because I have dynamic views in my nested state, each with a different controller.

Here is my app.js file

```
.state('index.region', {
    url: 'region',
    templateUrl: 'views/region.html',
    controller: 'RegionCtrl'
})
.state('index.region.detail', {
    url: '/:regionId',
    params: {
        detail: 'overview'
    },
    views: {
        'detail@index' : {
            templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
                if($stateParams.detail === 'info' || $stateParams.regionId) {
                    return 'views/regionInfo.html';
                } else if ($stateParams.detail === 'overview') {
                    return 'views/regionOverview.html';
                }
            }
        }
    },
})
```

HTML of `views/regionOverview.html`

```
<div ng-controller="RegionCtrl">
```

HTML of `views/regionInfo.html`

```
<div ng-controller="RegionInfoCtrl">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases you shouldn't have load the controller from the html, controller should be loaded from the state itself.

I'd suggest you to use `controllerProvider` option of state to load controller dynamically.

```
.state('index.region', {
    url: 'region',
    templateUrl: 'views/region.html',
    controller: 'RegionCtrl'
})
.state('index.region.detail', {
    url: '/:regionId',
    params: {
        detail: 'overview'
    },
    views: {
        'detail@index' : {
            templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
                if($stateParams.detail === 'info' || $stateParams.regionId) {
                    return 'views/regionInfo.html';
                } else if ($stateParams.detail === 'overview') {
                    return 'views/regionOverview.html';
                }
            },
            controllerProvider: function($stateParams){
                 if($stateParams.detail === 'info' || $stateParams.regionId) {
                    return 'RegionInfoCtrl';
                } else if ($stateParams.detail === 'overview') {
                    return ''; //return nothing
                }
            }
        }
    },
})
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/C9S0tEHOLUF2ToJZThJU?p=preview)

Comment: That's defiantly what I was originally looking for.  However `return " ";` isn't working

Comment: could you try out [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C9S0tEHOLUF2ToJZThJU?p=preview)

Comment: I am going to accept this answer however it did not fully solve my problem because apparently _[for children states] Nothing else is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc)_ from the ui-router docs

Comment: @tester123 may I know whats your exact goal? and did you checkout the plunkr?

Comment: Yes I did, but my goals is to have one of my children states views use the same controller as the parent since the logic in there is the same as what the child view needs. And then if the other view is requested use it's own controller.